# How to do an HTTP GET request to a json data file on my localhost

Tags: json, api, localhost, azure-logic-apps

WARNING: This may be a dumb question because my knowledge with API's is quite little.

I have a json file that's located on my localhost (`http://localhost/test/data.json`) and I was wondering if there was any way I could make a HTTP GET request to this file so I could get the JSON object returned that's inside it. I would want to make the API request with the HTTP connector from Azure's Logic app. Can anybody with some knowledge about it help me out here? Thanks :D

Screen of the data in the json file: [image: json_file]

Screen of the HTTP GET request in Logic Apps: [image: get_request]

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need to setup the on premises data gateway to connect to on premises systems or files. Once that is done you can access the json file using File Connector. Please check out following link for the official Microsoft documentation
[Connect to on-premises file systems with Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-file-connector)

That being said, I would say it would be easier if you just keep this json file in a blob storage account and then access it using the Blob Connectors in Logic Apps

Comment: Yes, I would love to do this, but the point of this Logic App is that other persons could use this without interfering with the Logic App itself, but rather change the input of the json file. Setting up an on premise data gateway won't work if it's for another persons on another computer, so. Thank you though for the answer!

Comment: Okay, in that case please share the entire requirement with us, because localhost or accessing the file using 127.0.0.1 will not work. The only way to access files on premises is by using on premises datagateway.